# How to add new line after curly bracket in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to find a way to configure Code Style Formatter in Visual Studio to add a new line after a curly bracket. I didn't find setting in the Code Style Formatter to help me with this. Do you have any suggestions?

I want to go from

```
public void Test() {
    // code
}
```

to

```
public void Test() {

    // code
}
```

Comment: Note that for C#, the typically used coding convention (used by Microsoft and adapted by many libraries), places the opening brace on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built-in formatter that automatically give spacing.
I know that if you open curly bracket and press enter, it automatically format it this way

```
public void Test(){
    //code
}
```

Comment: Yes.. but it does not really help me :) I want a empty line after the first bracket.